# how to convert underlying type to string at compile time without rtti?

Tags: c++

how do i can convert underlying type e.g. of enum to string at compile time?
and is it possible to do without declaring static structures for each type with manual strings and using of RTTI?

the expected result is almost same as using stringify macro operator (what i unfortunately tried) but with pre-evaluted type.

```
enum ESomeEnum : int {};
static_assert(MakeHashFNV1A(MAGIC_STRINGIFY(std::underlying_type_t<ESomeEnum>)) == MakeHashFNV1A("int"));
```

Comment: c++ doesn't have reflection (yet), so you'll need some static constexpr thing. You could write a function to do that for a specific enum; but without reflection you can't have code that converts any enum type to its type name, nor any value to its value name.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way, fundamentally.

Comment: What do you need this for? There is no standardized mapping from types to strings in the language at all. For example, why `"int"` instead of e.g. `"signed"`?

Comment: `typeid(std::underlying_type_t<ESomeEnum>).name()` almost gets you there, however it isn't `constexpr`, it isn't guaranteed to result in the string "int", and `==` on `const char *` is pointer equality, not string equality

Comment: @Caleth i had specified that rtti shouldn't be used

Comment: @not-a-real `typeid(` *type* `)` isn't rtti, you might be thinking of `typeid(` *expression* `)`

Comment: @Caleth Unfortunately GCC and Clang still don't accept `typeid` applied to a type if `-fno-rtti` is used. @not-a-real: If you don't want to use `typeid` at all, then there is no type to string map (not even an implementation-defined one) and you will simply have to map types to strings manually.

Comment: so thanks, i will treat @Elliott and Sam Varshavchik comments as answer here

Answer (score 2):

The is no need to stringify the type.  You can use [`std::underlying_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) to get the type of the underlying type of the `enum` and then compare that to the type you want want with [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).  That would give you

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, std::underlying_type_t<ESomeEnum>>);
```

Comment: the code i leave is just pseudo example, originally i need to fnv1a hash it

Comment: @not-a-real Can you add that more detail into your question?  Give it a more detailed(real) example what what you are actually doing?

Comment: @not-a-real After your update, I stand by my answer.  You don't need to hash anything when you can compare the types directly.  All you are doing is adding a layer of complexity that isn't needed.

Comment: i had specified what exactly do i need. the use of it aren't related to question in this case anyhow, and would be just senseless huge unrelated code span. i had just asked is it possible or no, nothing else.